# Directive with ng-transclude wraps html in ng-transclude element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive with an ng-repeat in the template, but I also want to have an ng-transclude after the repeater to allow a user to insert their own content. The problem is that the custom content is wrapped in an ng-transclude element when it is rendered and I don't want that.

Directive:

```
    angular.module("MyModule", [])
  .directive('myDirective', [function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: 'templates/template_view.html',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
        scope.nodes = [
          {
            "imageSource": "",
            "title": "Sample Title",
            "body": "Lorem ipsum and some other stuffs",
            "readMore": "",
            "date": "Mar 20"
          }
        ];

      }
    };
  }]);
```

Template:

```
<section>
  <div class="someClass" ng-repeat="node in nodes">
    <div>
      <img src="{{node.imageSource}}" alt="Picture">
    </div>
    <div class="content bounce-in">
      <h2>{{node.title}}</h2>
      <p>{{node.body}}</p>
      <a href="{{node.readMore}}" ng-show="{{node.readMore}}">Read more</a>
      <span>{{node.date}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</section>
```

Use:

```
<div my-directive>
  <div class="someClass">
    <h2>Title of section 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
    <span class="cd-date">Jan 14</span>
  </div>
  <div class="someClass">
    <h2>Title of section 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <span class="cd-date">Jan 18</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

What gets output:

```
<section my-directive="">
  <!-- ngRepeat: node in nodes -->
  <div class="someClass" ng-repeat="node in nodes">
    <div>
      <img src="" alt="Picture">
    </div>

    <div class="content bounce-in">
      <h2>Sample Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum and some other stuffs</p>
      <a href="" ng-show="">Read more</a>
      <span>Mar 20</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: node in nodes -->
  <div ng-transclude="">
    <div class="someClass">
      <h2>Title of section 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      <span class="cd-date">Jan 14</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="someClass">
    <h2>Title of section 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
    <span class="cd-date">Jan 18</span>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

I don't want the `<div ng-transclude>` element wrapping the transcluded data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `transclude` function passed to your directive's `comtroller` and `link` functions (in your case the `link` function which anyway is the more recommended approach) [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).
You get the `clone` of the transcluded content and you can do whatever you want with it:

```js
angular.module("MyModule", [])
  .directive('myDirective', [function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      transclude: true,
      replace: true,
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: 'templates/template_view.html',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transcludeFn) { 
        scope.nodes = [
          {
            "imageSource": "",
            "title": "Sample Title",
            "body": "Lorem ipsum and some other stuffs",
            "readMore": "",
            "date": "Mar 20"
          }
        ];
        
        transcludeFn(function (clone) {
          element.find('a-selector-for-the-ng-translude-element').after(clone).remove();
        });

      }
    };
  }]);
```

Haven't tested the above code...

Also, re-consider the use of `replace: true` as it's deprecated since Angular 1.3